# How to change pop up speed of "Press and Hold"

Tags: macos, keyboard

When pressing and holding a keyboard button, i.e. an `a`, a character pops up.

[image: PressAndHold]

I recall that I was somehow able to change how long I need to hold a key until the Picker pops up on Yosemite. 
I cannot find a place to change the popup speed on Mavericks though.

`defaults read -g | grep -i press` does not return anything.

Comment: I'd say not a dupe, as the option wasn't directly switchable before Yosemite, so the answer wasn't as simple.

Comment: … and, apologies… I only just realised the question is for Mavericks <facepalm>

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate, since it seems there has been a change in how this setting could be set. 
I believe it was possible to set this via `defaults write someoption` in Yosemite.

Comment: Did it work from prefs in Mavericks too?

Comment: It seems to have worked, yes.

Comment: Cool - it may be worth re-titling the question to make it less-specific, then, for future Googlers.

Comment: Not sure how though. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Done. You can always edit your own question with the edit button just underneath it. Editing others' questions needs more rep, but you can always build towards that :)

Comment: I was actually referring to the wording. ;) thx though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this works for both Mavericks & Yosemite...

You can do it right from the prefs

System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard

Set Delay until repeat

It works for the accent pop-up just the same as it does for 'regular' key repeat

[image]